# Celery and Redis - Filter and Insert to MySQL Tables

Tags: python, mysql, redis, celery

I have a stock market ticker data subscription, and I store this data in MySQL using Redis and Celery.

I have 2 python files.  One is Kite_Ticker.py which has the api_keys for the ticker subscription, and the tokens (scrip IDs) that I have subscribed to.  As an example, I have subscribed to tokens 1234 and 5678.

Second python file is the Py_MySQL.py which has the celery task and insertion of data from the subscribed tokens to the MySQL database.  I am inserting the data to two different tables (ticks1 and ticks2).  Currently, data from both the instrument_tokens (1234 and 5678) get inserted into the MySQL tables (ticks1 and ticks2).  I would like instrument_token = 1234 to be inserted to ticks1 table and instrument_token = 5678 to be inserted to ticks2 table.  How can this be done?

I appreciate any help as I am new to celery and redis.

thank you.

---

Here is the code:

Kite_Ticker.py

```
import datetime
import sys
import logging
from kiteconnect import KiteTicker
from Py_MySQL import *
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

api_k="abc"
api_s="xyz"
api_a="123"

tokens=[1234,5678]

kws = KiteTicker(api_k, api_a)

def on_ticks(ws,ticks):
    insert_tick=insert_ticks.delay(ticks)
    print(datetime.datetime.now().time())

def on_connect(ws,response):
    ws.subscribe(tokens)
    ws.set_mode(ws.MODE_FULL,tokens)

kws.on_ticks=on_ticks
kws.on_connect=on_connect
kws.connect()
```

---

Py_MySQL.py

```
import sys
import pymysql
import logging
from celery import Celery

app=Celery('tasks',broker='redis://127.0.0.1:6379/7')

insert_into_table1='insert into ticks1(timestamp,instrument_token,last_price,volume,open,high,low) values(%(timestamp)s,%(instrument_token)s,%(last_price)s,%(volume)s,%(open)s,%(high)s,%(low)s)'

insert_into_table2='insert into ticks2(timestamp,instrument_token,last_price,volume,open,high,low) values(%(timestamp)s,%(instrument_token)s,%(last_price)s,%(volume)s,%(open)s,%(high)s,%(low)s)'

@app.task
def insert_ticks(ticks):
    db=pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',user='root',password='abcxyz123',database='sm')
    c=db.cursor()
    for tick in ticks:
        c.execute(insert_into_table1,{'timestamp':tick['timestamp'],
                                    'instrument_token':tick['instrument_token'],
                                    'last_price':tick['last_price'],
                                    'volume':tick['volume'],
                                    'open':tick['ohlc']['open'],
                                    'high':tick['ohlc']['high'],
                                    'low':tick['ohlc']['low']})

        c.execute(insert_into_table2,{'timestamp':tick['timestamp'],
                                    'instrument_token':tick['instrument_token'],
                                    'last_price':tick['last_price'],
                                    'volume':tick['volume'],
                                    'open':tick['ohlc']['open'],
                                    'high':tick['ohlc']['high'],
                                    'low':tick['ohlc']['low']})

    try:
        db.commit()
    except Exception:
        db.rollback()
```

Comment: Do you want to make this generalize or specific for these two only __(1234 and 5678)__

Comment: In reality, I have 2000 or more instrument tokens.  Out of which, I want some of them to be inserted to ticks1 table and the others to ticks2 table.  If the only way is to be specific, I can include the specific tokens in the python code if required.

Comment: So how will you differentiate between ticks1 tokens and ticks2 tokens ?

Comment: In the example above, I can have all instrument tokens (1234 and 5678) inserted to ticks1 table.  This does not require any change to the code, as all messages gathered by celery will be pushed to ticks1.  However, I want to hard code insertion of instrument token 1234 only to ticks2 table.  How can this be done?

Comment: Then you can simple check with __if tick['instrument_token'] == 1234: insert_to_table2()__

Comment: Thank you Deepak.  I tried to complicate it in my head.  This was a simple solution.  thank you once again.